# How to configure various supervisors for a nimbus in storm?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, nimbus, topology

I have a nimbus server and 3 other supervisor servers. And I have 11 storm topologies running. But all of them are running in the Nimbus only. How to configure the other supervisors so that the topologies get distributed among various supervisors. Which configuration files I have to change?

Comment: Could you provide a storm.yaml for one of your supervisor servers?

Comment: What does Storm UI show? Are all supervisors registered at Nimbus correctly? What is you topology parameter `number.workers`?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, Someone else set up the supervisor and nimbus. Can you please tell me how to check whether supervisors are registered at nimbus or not. Attached the Storm UI. Also you can see the number.workers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is something funny going on. For the two hosts `corona-stage-storm-supervisor-01` and `corona-stage-storm-supervisor-02` there are two supervisors each. However, a host should have only one supervisor running. I would assume that this "confuses" Nimbus and it uses remaining host (`corona-storm-nimbus-01`) that does only have a single supervisor running.

See Storm documentation for more detail (and talk to your admin who did the setup):

- https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.0/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster.html

*About number of workers:* this parameter defines how many worker JVM are use for a topology (the supervisor JVM starts worker JVM that do the actual work -- supervisors are basically "host local master" for coordination). You can set it in you job configuration via `conf.setNumWorkers(int)`. If you want a topology to spread out over multiple hosts, you need to increase the parameter. Nevertheless, for multiple topologies as in your case, a value of one might also be ok -- different topologies should run of different host, independently of this parameter.

See Storm documentation for more details:

- https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.0/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html

Comment: I am also not getting any response from supervisor while pinging from nimbus and vice versa. it means the nimbus and supervisors are not mapped and connected. How to configure them so that nimbus and supervisor openstack server can talk to each other?

Comment: @tanmay2507 did you get the solution. I am also facing the same issue where nimbus and supervisors are not able to communicate to each other.